# Python PIP failed to build pandas typed-ast

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, windows, windows-11

Getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\user1\source\repos\proj1>pip install -v -r requirements.txt
Using pip 22.1.2 from C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
Collecting alembic==1.3.2
  Using cached alembic-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

...


     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\pandas\_libs\missing.cp310-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\pandas\_libs\missing.cp310-win_amd64.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  building 'pandas._libs.parsers' extension
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -I.\pandas\_libs -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -IC:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3r6qbn25\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcpandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.obj
  io.c
  pandas/_libs/src/klib\khash.h(563): warning C4090: 'function': different 'const' qualifiers
  pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(139): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier
  pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(139): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'rv'
  pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(139): error C2065: 'rv': undeclared identifier
  pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(145): error C2065: 'rv': undeclared identifier
  pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(145): warning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
  pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(146): error C2065: 'rv': undeclared identifier
  pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(157): error C2065: 'rv': undeclared identifier
  pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(158): error C2065: 'rv': undeclared identifier
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\KRZYSZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxaes1lro'
  cwd: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\pandas_91f4937d2154484f8d45759038caf4a5
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
  Running command python setup.py bdist_wheel
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\typed_ast
  copying typed_ast\ast27.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\typed_ast
  copying typed_ast\ast3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\typed_ast
  copying typed_ast\conversions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\typed_ast
  copying typed_ast\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\typed_ast
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\typed_ast\tests
  copying ast3\tests\test_basics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\typed_ast\tests
  running build_ext
  building '_ast27' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\ast27
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\ast27\Custom
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\ast27\Parser
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\ast27\Python
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iast27/Include -IC:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcast27/Custom/typed_ast.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\ast27/Custom/typed_ast.obj
  typed_ast.c
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(32): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(32): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(32): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(32): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(33): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(33): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(33): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(33): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(398): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(398): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(398): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(398): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(400): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(400): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(400): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(400): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(402): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(402): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(402): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(402): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(404): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(404): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(404): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(404): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(406): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(406): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(406): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(406): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(410): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(410): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(410): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(410): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(413): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(413): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(413): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(413): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(415): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(415): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(415): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(415): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(417): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(417): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(417): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(417): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(420): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(420): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(420): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(420): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(423): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(423): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(423): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(423): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(426): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(426): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(426): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(426): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(429): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(429): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(429): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(429): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(432): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(432): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(432): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(432): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(435): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(435): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(435): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(435): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(438): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(438): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(438): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(438): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(441): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(441): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(441): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(441): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(444): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(444): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(444): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(444): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(447): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(447): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(447): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(447): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(449): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(449): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(449): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(449): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(451): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(451): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(451): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(451): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(454): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(454): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(454): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(454): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(457): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(457): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(457): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(457): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(459): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(459): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize

  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )
      sys.exit(1)

  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__

  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"

  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-y63vmciy\\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\\setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4h5mqfot'
  cwd: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y63vmciy\typed-ast_10428a92f401481e846b8e7075b4f540\
  Building wheel for typed-ast (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for typed-ast
  Running setup.py clean for typed-ast
  Running command python setup.py clean
  running clean
  removing 'build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310' (and everything under it)
  removing 'build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310' (and everything under it)
  'build\bdist.win-amd64' does not exist -- can't clean it
  'build\scripts-3.10' does not exist -- can't clean it
  removing 'build'
Failed to build pandas typed-ast
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

C:\Users\user1\source\repos\proj1>
```

Developer machine is:
Windows 11 Pro 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor 11th Gen Intel i7
Python 3.10.5

There are a number of questions I have about this:

- Why is it that pandas & typed-ast have to be built on my machine, does the binary not exist somewhere for download?
- How would I know which Visual Studio Build tools (VS2019 or VS2022) I need to have installed in order to build the library?
- Should I submit this as a bug on https://github.com/python/cpython ?

Comment: are you using windows11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try again with python3.9 instead of python3.10

for all 3 additional questions, here is your answer:

> We do not support Python 3.10 officially, and only release wheels for linux so far, but not Windows or MacOS. Support for Python 3.10 is planned on either the next release or the release after that.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43969#issuecomment-940625041

Comment: I updated the requirements.txt file from having "pandas==1.1.5" to "pandas".  Since as of 7/12/22 the latest tag was set to v1.4.3 I decided to try it and didn't get errors.  The requirements file was pointing to an older version of it.

I also changed the requirements.txt file from having "typed-ast==1.4.2" and just deleted it.  The command finished without having to build any additional libraries.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47681